# Test coverage tool that shows call graph of untested new code from a merge

Tags: automated-testing, tools, coverage

I'm looking for a test coverage tool that can show the call path/call graph of new untested code that  came from a merge.

Example: I have a git repo (on github or bitbucket) and a test suite that covers X% on master, some other developer wants to contribute and do a fork and a pull request as usual, but he/she didn't included the tests (for many reasons). Then the tool show the untested call graphs that only came after the integration of this new code.

Comment: What is your development stack? e.g. programming language and test-framework you want coverage for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NielsvanReijmersdal, I don't have a specific stack, I'm a master student and this was an idea that I had and just wanna know if already there is a similar tool, but the main focus is Java.

Comment: Visual Studio has such a tool for Unit Tests.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Diff-Cover: https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff-cover

> Diff coverage is the percentage of **new or modified lines** that are
>   covered by tests. This provides a clear and achievable standard for
>   code review: If you touch a line of code, that line should be covered.

Seems Diff-Cover uses [Cobertura](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura) XML coverage reports, those might or might not be available for the stack you are using.

> Cobertura XML coverage reports can be generated with many coverage
>   tools, including:
>
> - Cobertura (Java)
> - coverage.py (Python)
> - JSCover (JavaScript)